# Bad Windows License Key

Tags: windows-7, download, license

I have several Windows 7 Ultimate license keys that I downloaded a while ago from when I had an MSDN subscription.  These are legitimate keys and have not been used elsewhere by me.

Today I went to download from [Download Windows 7 Disc Images (ISO Files)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7).  This page wanted to know my license key before it would initiate a download, and when I put one of my keys the site responded with:

> **Error**
>
> The product key you provided is for a product not currently supported
>   by this site or may be invalid. Please try again or visit the
>   Microsoft Support Contact Us page for assistance.

Is this a genuine problem with my license key, or a problem with a license key that is associated with the Ultimate version?

I do have (pre SP1) ISO files of the same vintage as the keys I have, but I wanted to download something more moderne with the latests updates already baked in.

After a bit of searching around I did find in the [Windows Download FAQ](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/faq)

> **My Windows 7 product key won't verify. What's the problem?**
>
> The most common issue is the use of a product key for a product not
>   currently supported by the site such as an Upgrade key, an MSDN key,
>   product keys for pre-installed media or an Enterprise edition key. For
>   access to MSDN products or Enterprise edition visit the MSDN Portal or
>   the Volume Licensing Service Center. Upgrades and pre-installed media
>   are not currently supported by the tools on the site. If you believe
>   you have a valid product key and are still receiving an error, please
>   contact Support.

Thus the problem was the type of key I had, so the best solution for me right now is magicandre's answer

Comment: I would be surprised if a retail download would allow an MSDN product key.

Comment: *"I do have ISO files of the same vintage as the keys I have, but I wanted to download something more moderne with the latests updates already baked in."*  In your current situation, I would utilize the ISO images you already have.  Remember that SP1 for Windows 7 was actually released six years ago, and the images you are trying to download probably won't have any additional updates integrated into them after that.  One way or another, a clean install of Windows 7 involves a lot of Windows Updates.

Comment: @Run5k Yesterday I started a W7 system that was last run and updated about 4 months ago.  It sucked down a bunch of updates.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Why should the source of the key matter?  Ultimate is a retail product.  I have a valid Ultimate key.  After the install the system will still phone home to validate the key used for the installation.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I take it back.  I just found a FAQ on the MS site that clearly states what you said.

Comment: As I said, there is no escaping the fact that if you really want to install Windows 7, you can anticipate a lot of Windows Updates in the aftermath.  It is highly unlikely that any image you will find has something more than current Service Pack 1 on the disc.  As a result, I would stick with the ISO files you already have.

Comment: I posted steps to get ISOs. But this is only the Win7 SP1 from 2011. MS never provides any ISOs with updates included.

Comment: you can use Microsoft Windows and Office ISO Download Tool from HeiDoc.net, it's a thirdparty tool that will give you the ISO links from microsoft without product key validation. You can read more here : https://www.howtogeek.com/186775/how-to-download-windows-7-8-and-8.1-installation-media-legally/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download any Windows 7 ISO [from this page](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/index.php?lang=en) without providing any product key. It generates valid download links from **Microsoft servers** for all Windows versions.

- Select `Windows 7 Sp1 (Build 7601)` and `Windows 7 Ultimate Sp1`

[image]

- now select the Language you want to download:

[image]

- and finally select the architecture (32 or 64Bit):

[image]

- now you see a download button on the right side.

[image]

Now download the ISO from the link , which is valid for 24 hours.